# SQL Developer arabic query result not showing properly

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem showing Arabic data in my query result in sqldeveloper.

I have  NLS_CHARACTERSET= WE8ISO8859P9.

I did change in oracle sqldeveloper settings the enconding to ISO-8859-9, iv change it in regedit as well, i still cant see my Arabic data. its shows like this : 'Çáãíãæäí'

The picture showing the problem:
[Arabic Data problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deSpA.png)

Comment: check your font, and/or search 'arabic sql developer' here for other answers

Comment: Thank you for responding, i've change my font as well , same result

Comment: Then it's not stored correctly in the database, so it's a server issue, not s client problem.